# Windows application that remembers user input

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows

I am new to windows development so would request everyone to bear with me when I ask some real basic questions.
I want to have a windows application which can remember the user input from the previous time. So basically what I am thinking is that I can take the user input and write it into an XML file and read from it when the application loads again. But the problem is that I have to finally distribute only the .exe file. Hence I cannot have an .xml file sitting next to my exe to read from it. I cannot use an embedded resource because I cannot write into it.(or Have I misunderstood this?).
So what would be the best alternative? I know for a  fact that this user input would not be more than 1 line (2 or 3 words to be more specific). Hence I was hoping for a simple solution.

Comment: You might be interested in Settings in C#, take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx as Yvette said, your question is too broad so I did not post this as an answer.

Comment: There's no way you can achieve that without using some external (I.E external to your EXE file) storage. Either file, Windows Registry, or database.

Comment: I would just have the program create the xml file in the users appdata folder when it first starts up.

Comment: No reason that this question is unanswerable, voting to re-open. The simple solution is to store your data in the AppData folder where it belongs in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the other answers are neglecting the solution that is custom-made for this scenario:  [user settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397750.aspx).  Add a settings file to the project, and define the settings that you need; set their scope to "User", and define a default value if desired.  Then in your code, retrieve and update the settings using `Properties.Settings.Default.SomeProp`.

This approach allows you to create a data structure that gets persisted to the local file system, per user.  It also has the advantage that the settings can be preserved, even when you push an application update out to the users.

Comment: Thanks.. That perfectly fits my requirements. Considering the user input is less than 2 or 3 words I was reluctant in the first place to create a separate xml file for it.

Answer (score 2):

Saving the user input on an XML file really doesn't stop you from distributing the exe file, does it? Write your code to create the XML file if it doesn't exist, so when someone executes your application for the first time and enters input, the XML file will be created and the input will get saved.

Although not recommended, you can consider saving the values in the Windows registry as well.

Comment: I agree with this, but don't try to save the data file in the same directory as the executable. You'll run afoul of permissions problems. Standard users shouldn't have write privileges to the application folder. Save the data to the Application Data folder instead. And don't bother with the Registry at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store "something", you need to store it "somewhere". This "somewhere" is usually a database, a file (txt, xml, ...), Windows registry, remote server etc, it all depends on the specific needs. If you can't, your only option is to use a temporary memory collection/object, but that will "disappear" the moment you close the application. You can't have an .exe file, that would do all the work on by itself.

You don't need to ship your application with multiple files, you can always create them on-fly when needed. Just make sure you have the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deploy another file.  Simply create an XMLDocument (call it, say, xmlDoc), populate the info in it, and write it using the xmlDoc.Save(myFileName).
The trick is where to save 'myFileName'.  Generally, windows will not allow an app to write to anything under Program Files, so you can't just write to the application directory.  My Documents is usually a good place to save file.  Do something like this:

string myDocumentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string myFileName = string.format(@"{0}\MyAppSettings.txt", myDocumentsFolder");
xmloc.Save(myFileName);

Comment: The "My Documents" folder is for data that the user creates and saves themselves. It is *not* designed for applications to store files. That's what the Application Data (AppData) folder is for. (No, you're not the first person to make this mistake. Lots of major vendors do, too. That doesn't make it right. I hate installing software that clutters up *My* Documents folder.)